# Testing Abstract Document Repository which interacts with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, unit-testing, symfony, phpunit, document-repository

Heey all,

I'm having troubles to set up a testcase.
I have a plain symfony 3 project connected to mongodb. I have multiple documents which each needs an extra method to query the database. The method will get the last document inserted in the collection and is called `findLatestInserted()`.

This specific function was duplicated in each document repository. So I decided to extract it and create a class `BaseDocumentRepository` which extends the default `DocumentRepository`. All of my document repositories still have their own DocumentRepository class let's say: `CpuInfoRepository`, `RamInfoRepository`. These classes do offer a few extra methods to query the mongodb database and the **one in common**: `findLatestInserted()`

It all works fine but just in case i'd wanted to write a unit test for this method `findLatestInserted()`.

I have a test database called prototyping-test which is used to create a document and query it and check the result. Afterwards it'll clear itself so no documents stays in. For each repository there's a specific url to post data to to create a file in the database. To create a CpuInfo collection you'll post data to `http://localhost:8000/ServerInfo/CreateCpuInfo`. To create a RamInfo collection you'll post data to `http://localhost:8000/ServerInfo/CreateRamInfo`.

So here follows my question how would i write a test to test the method `findLatestInserted()`?

this is what i've tried so far:

```
public function testFindLatestInserted()
{
    $client = self::createClient();
    $crawler = $client->request('POST',
        '/ServerInfo/CreateCpuInfo',
        [
            "hostname" => $this->hostname,
            "timestamp" => $this->timestamp,
            "cpuCores" => $this->cpuCores,
            "cpu1" => $this->cpu1,
            "cpu2" => $this->cpu2
        ]);
    $this->assertTrue($client->getResponse()->isSuccessful());

    $serializer = $this->container->get('jms_serializer');
    $cpuInfo = $serializer->deserialize($client->getResponse()->getContent(), 'AppBundle\Document\CpuInfo', 'json');

    $expected = $this->dm->getRepository("AppBundle:CpuInfo")->find($cpuInfo->getId());
    $stub = $this->getMockForAbstractClass('BaseDocumentRepository');

    $actual = $this->dm
        ->getRepository('AppBundle:CpuInfo')
        ->findLatestInserted();

    $this->assertNotNull($actual);
    $this->assertEquals($expected, $actual);
}
```

At the line `$actual = $this->dm->getRepository('AppBundle:CpuInfo')->findLatestInserted();` i got stuck. As this would only test for CpuInfo while there is RamInfo too (and some other classes not mentioned here). How would one approach this setting?
I specificly want to test the method `findLatestInserted()` on the level of the abstract class instead of the concrete classes.

Please help me out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of testing the whole stack, just concentrate on testing `findLatestInserted()` in concrete classes.

Inject MondoDB stub into `AppBundle:CpuInfo` and check if `findLatestInserted()` returns expected value.
Do the same for `AppBundle:RamInfo`.

Avoid testing abstract classes, always test concrete classes.
In future, you may decide not to inherit from `BaseDocumentRepository` and may not notice that new implementation of `findLatestInserted()` fails.